# how to deploy a mule ws with mule-standalone-3.5.0

Tags: deployment, xsd, mule

I create a mule app with mule studio.
It works fine when I run it as a mule application with mule studio.
when I want to deploy it by mule-standalone-3.5.0 runtime.
it throws an exception:

`org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc-ee:oracle-data-source'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description,.....}' is expected.`

Comment: Add full exception stack trace. what version of Mule Studio you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using Mule Studio enterprise edition and deploying the application in Mule standlone community edition...
The Exception shows that `jdbc-ee:oracle-data-source` is of Mule studio Enterprise edition and cannot be deployed in Mule standalone community Edition ..You can do either things as follows:-

- Use Mule Studio community Edition and deploy into Mule standalone
  community Edition
- or Use Mule Studio Enterprise Edition and deploy into Mule standalone
  Enterprise Edition...

Since You must be using Mule Studio Enterprise, you need to change your Standalone to Enterprise Edition .. or use Mule Studio Community Edition

Answer (score 0):

**Change Runtime of Existing Project:** http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime

Export it and run in standalone.

Or use standalone-ee version

Answer (score 0):

@Anirban is right about how the cause of the problem and how to solve it. But I have to recommend you to use the new [Database Module](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector) instead of JDBC transport. This is a new Community feature released in Mule ESB 3.5.0. There are several [examples](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Database+Connector+Examples) and [resources](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fmFescqdao)) about its advantages over JDBC transport and how to use it.
Regards.